# How can i solve Android studio 4.2 Rendering Problem?

Tags: android, android-studio, rendering

I've installed the 4.2 today and since this operation, I'm not able to see some pages created in my old files, it gives me this error:

Render problem:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor861.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.lambda$createViewFromCustomInflater$0(BridgeInflater.java:259)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromCustomInflater(BridgeInflater.java:285)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:122)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:928)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:948)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1002)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:309)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:354)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:431)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:141)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:710)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$6(RenderTask.java:865)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$2.run(RenderExecutor.kt:174)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:47)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:693)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getType(BridgeTypedArray.java:1024)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getType(BridgeTypedArray.java:809)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getValue(BridgeTypedArray.java:778)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.peekValue(BridgeTypedArray.java:847)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5951)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:996)
    at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:87)
    at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:83)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:74)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:69)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createEditText(AppCompatViewInflater.java:209)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:127)
    ... 26 more
```

Is someone able to help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 40):

Deleting `android:autofillHints=""` from EditText solved the problem with the Render.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28923566)

Comment: @Tomerikoo: It seems like their edit _does_ offer an answer, but it's buried under the original text. Kudrnac should edit this answer to focus on the solution, instead of burying it under a different suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is caused by `android:autofillHints=""`
Just remove it and it will render correctly. Ensure you also check to have             `android:hint="@string/unclock_code"` to avoid lint issues.

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by the `android:autofillHints=""`.
To solve it, just remove the `android:autofillHints=""`.

Android Studio will still release warnings. To solve this, just add the code:
`android:importantForAutofill="no"`

Answer (score 2):

this often occurs when you've add new libraries to the project via gradle and your ide is not properly synced and indexed of the new classes added to the library. Hence the UI render produces error rendering the new UI elements classes.

Just clean your project by Build -> clean project. Then again click Build -> rebuild project. Once the grade sync is complete, you won't see this message.

If this doesn't help you, then under file -> invalidate caches and restart. This should sort out the issue!!

Comment: This worked for me, and the other answers made no sense for me since I didn't have autofillHints anyways.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mtm9.png)In case of switch replace :

### wrong

com.google.android.material.materialswitch.MaterialSwitch

### corret

*com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).